# Append HTML before hi <a>hi</a>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add some HTML before

```
<a class="hello">here add some html hi</a>
```

on ready function in jQuery, I already tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.home').after().append('<p>hi</p>');
})
```

also, tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul li:a').text().before().append('<p>hi</p>');
})
```

Comment: You describe what you tried. **You do not describe how it failed.** Also, there is no pseudo class `:a`.

Comment: You want to append a html element behind another element using jquery? That is to said you actually want to prepend . prepend adds html element before an element in the parent div. So what you will used is the prepend() method like this: $('a').prepend('<p>Hi</p>'); try it and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla solution:

```js
const setup = () => {
 document.querySelector('.hello').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<p>hi</p>');
};

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<a class="hello">here add some html hi</a>
```

Comment: <div class="nav" id="navbar">
 <ul class="slimmenu" id="slimmenu">
     <li><a href="{{url('/')}}" class="home"> append herer Home</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
</div>       how to append in this case before Home. add this html   <i class="fa fa-home"> 
 </i>  by jquery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/crkq0h15/2 , you might realize now what jQuery actually does.

Comment: Thanks you give me best solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is going to be the first link on the page(If not, just change the 0):

```js
    // The current HTML
    var currentHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("hello")[0].innerHTML;
    // Sets the innerHTML to the new HTML + the current HTML
    document.getElementsByClassName("hello")[0].innerHTML = "New HTML " + currentHTML;
```

```html
<a class="hello">Hi</a>
```

You could also add `document.onload = function(){}` or `window.onload` = function(){} if you decide to implement this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: <div class="nav" id="navbar">
 <ul class="slimmenu" id="slimmenu">
     <li><a href="{{url('/')}}" class="home"> append herer Home</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
</div>       how to append in this case before Home. add this html   <i class="fa fa-home"> 
 </i>  by jquery